# Memory Leak on Windows 10 - EtwD/Etwr

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, windows-10

I am having issues with a memory leak that is eventually consuming all my RAM, even if I don't use my computer after a while. This is utterly annoying, mainly because I have to reboot my system after a while.

I have tried to trace back the cause of the leak with `poolmon.exe,` and apparently, it has to do with the *Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)*. I have tried to disable some of the logs in *computer management->performance->Data Collector Sets* and tried to trace precisely which one is the one causing the issue with `logman/xperf`.

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone!

## Details

### System

- Razer Blade 15 Advanced Model - QHD 240Hz - GeForce RTX 3070 - Black ([Reference here](https://www.razer.com/hk-en/gaming-laptops/Razer-Blade-15/RZ09-0409JED3-R341))
- RAM 64GB
- Windows 10 Pro 21H2 19044.1889

Here is a screenshot of the task manager showing the memory performance in a session when this memory leak happens.

Image:
[Task Manager Paged/Non-paged pool consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VEM2.png)

As you can see, it is consuming 63.4 GB of memory as a paged pool resource!

Image:
[poolmon.exe debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quVy3.png)

According to Microsoft, these are the values for these tags:

```
EtwR - nt!etw       - Etw Registration
EtwD - nt!etw       - Etw DataBlock
```

Comment: Interestingly, the exact same problem shows up on my computer for quite some time, a couple of weeks probably. I suspect some kind of driver or system utility that has lately been upgraded to cause the leak.
What I notice is that the amount of used memory decreases slowly after reaching a peak. I have a vague suspicion that it might have to do with downloading large files, but could not verify yet.

Comment: Any updates here? I have the same issue a few days now. EtwR uses almost 25GB of RAM.

Comment: I've only experienced this once in combination with SteamVR and audio device issues. So I opted out of SteamVR beta and Steam beta and restarted. It's really not enough to draw any conclusions, but it hasn't happened since.